# Select fields from dbf file

Tags: python, sql, dbf

I use [dbf 0.95.004](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf), I need to select one field from table. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10462912/1751039), [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/dbf/dbf-pysrc.html#sql)

```
import dbf
table = dbf.Table('my.dbf').open()
records = table.sql('select name')
```

But I have error:

```
AttributeError: 'Db3Table' object has no attribute 'sql'
```

I open **dbf.py** and find

```
def pql(records, command):
```

Not `def sql(records, command):` like in the [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/dbf/dbf-pysrc.html#sql).

Ofcourse, I can do like this without sql:

```
for record in table:
    record['name']
```

But I need to use sql-select.
So, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies (x2), the docs are way out of date.  You can either use `dbf.pql(table, 'blah blah')` (named that way because it is a very limited sql-like syntax), or `table.query()`.  These are not well developed routines as I found using normal Python syntax easier.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Db3Table' object has no attribute 'pql'`